# Create new bean instance on each servlet request

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, scope

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
      homePageController = (HomePageControllerV2) BeanLoader.getBean("homePageControllerV2");
   }
}
```

*whenever i hit to servlet from multiple machine. i still get the same instance of homePageController. is there any way can get diffrent instance of object homePageControllerper servlet request.*

i have tired with changing the scope of bean to **prototype**. but still faced the same issue.

Comment: If you need new instance on each request You can use [@RequestScope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/annotation/RequestScope.html) annotation on bean